# How to send Ctrl+F key combination in Autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to do run an Autohotkey script that would send a bunch of keystrokes to an active window (e.g windows explorer). I tried several things, but it all fails when it comes to ctrl...

^!r::

Send {^f}

Send {Up}

The up key gets send, but ctrl+f does not happen. Read the manual, tried several applications as active windows, and still no luck. Seems very simple, but ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
F1::^f
```

This makes F1 behave as it is a Ctrl+F , F1 doesn't exist anymore
If you wan't to keep the old keys add ~

```
~F1::^f
```

this will fire both F1 and ^f

if you wan't more

```
    F1::
       Send,^f
       Send,{up}
    return
```

Maybe you had multiple scripts with the same hotkey -> ^!r , if you do that the hotkey might not work properly.

Comment: thanks, this worked:
F1::
       Send,^f
       Send,{up}
    return